# swift Kingfisher and MPMediaItemArtwork

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I am currently printing out the image for now playing using the following code.

```
if var strUrl = nowplaying.data.first?.track.imageurl {

                                  strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
                                  self.imageurl.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: strUrl), placeholder: nil)


                              }
```

I want to send that image to

`MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`

which is in the following function

```
func nowplaying(artist: String, song: String, artwork: String){     
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
      MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:song,
      MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artist,
      MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:artwork
    ]
}
```

Currently I have   `MusicPlayer.shared.nowplaying(artist:  $0.track.artist, song: $0.track.title, artwork: $0.track.imageurl)` which sends the data correctly but then crashes - and I know it is because you can't have a remote image in the artwork section for `MPMediaItemProperty`...

So I am wondering how do I cache the image and send it?

**code tried**

```
let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)) { size -> UIImage in

       KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with:  cover, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
        print(image)

        })
       return UIImage()
      }
```

it prints in the console log

```
Optional(<UIImage:0x280a4e0a0 anonymous {500, 500}>)
```

but seems not to print it to the

> MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork

Answer (score 0):

You can save an image in the cache and can retrieve it whenever you need.

```
let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: "my_cache_key")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
```

You can retrieve an image from the cache by using

```
cache.retrieveImage(forKey: "cacheKey") { result in
    //Your code
)}
```

For more information, you can check this link https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Hope this works...

Answer (score 0):

The value of `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` should be `MPMediaItemArtwork` class, not URL or String. In those class you can load UIImage async and set as an artwork in Command Center

Here is a working example with Kingfisher (please update it according your model structure):

```
  ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(
    with: artworkUrl,
    options: nil,
    progressBlock: nil) { (result) in
      guard let image = try? result.get().image else { return }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
          MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: song,
          MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: artist,
          MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: image
        ]
      }
}
```

Comment: let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)) { size -> UIImage in
        

             let cover = cover.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
            self.artwork.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: cover), placeholder: nil)
              return UIImage()
        }

Did not work

Comment: @RussellHarrower at least you should return your loaded UIImage object, not empty image that I used for example

Comment: @RussellHarrower that info is useless if you don't specify where and when you get the error